# Is it possible to check double and char data types

Tags: c#, asp.net

One interviewer asked this question to me ,when I am checking it's working how it is possible to check type of char and double?
Please any one explain me.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double d=0;

        if((double)d == 'c')
        {
            Console.WriteLine("working");
        }
        else 
        { 
            Console.WriteLine("not"); 
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean "check type of char and double"? what's the input?

Comment: You can use typeof to check type.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Char` type is actually a *16-bit integer*, so you can compare them if you like:

```
  Double left = 'B'; // <- 66.0
  Char right = 'A';  // <- it's 16-bit int == 65 in fact 

  if (left > right) {...}
```

There's one issue, however: you should not use `==` or `!=` *without tolerance*, since `Double` as well as other *floating point types* has round-up error, so

```
  Double left = 66;
```

could be in fact `66.000000000002` or `65.9999999999998`. Something like that:

```
  Double left = 'B'; // <- 66.0
  Char right = 'A';  // <- it's 16-bit int == 65 in fact 

  // (left == right) comparison with tolerance
  // Since right is integer in fact, 0.1 tolerance is OK
  if (Math.Abs(left - right) < 0.1) {...}
```

Comment: THANKS IF (DOUBLE != NULL) IT SHOWING WARNING ALlways TRUE Y?

Comment: Double is a struct, it can't be null. That's why "if" is always true

Comment: id we double? =0  than? means differnt between double =0 and double? =0

Comment: Double? is in fact a shortcut for Nullable<Double>. That changes the matter. So double? != null has sence. As for Double == 0 and Double? == 0 they work the same way

Answer (score 2):

you can use the normal `GetType()` and `typeof()` to check type of an any object. like this

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      double d=0;

      if(d.GetType() == typeof(Char))
      {
        Console.WriteLine("working");
      }
      else 
      { 
        Console.WriteLine("not"); 
      }

      Console.ReadLine();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually when you are trying to compare any numeric value to char value, its not giving you any compile time or run time error, because char is actually represent int16  or 16-bit integer value, so when you try to compare double, integer or long with it, it will simple compare its ASCII value of that character with it. here is some example...

```
double d = 65;
if (d == 'A')
{
    Console.WriteLine("working");
}
else { Console.WriteLine("not"); }
```

the above code's out put is "Working" because char "A" ASCII value is 65 and you are comparing it with 65 so it true with if condition.